# No such file in the directory

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am New To Python, I Need to pass a list of URLs as input to the script, I used `f1=open` to read and `f2=open` for writing output

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time
import bs4
import sys



f1=open("links.txt","r")
urls=f1.readlines()
urls=[urls.split()[0] for x in urls]
f1.close()

f2=open("a.txt","w")
for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(driver.current_url)
    f2.write(str(driver.current_url)+"\n")

f2.close()
```

But i got this erro

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'links.txt'`

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'links.txt'

The error mentioned that file is not present in the directory.

Please note that you need to check the file name. I believe you have created text file by right click on new text file and then named it as  `links.txt` therefore when you open the file name changed to `links.txt.txt` just **save as this file** as mentioned in snapshot.

[image]

And try below options.

> f1=open("links.txt","r")

Or you could do instead of save as the file as mentioned above.

> f1=open("links.txt.txt","r")

Or You can use full path of the file to open the file.

> f1=open(r"D:\Foldername\links.txt.txt","r")

OR

> f1=open(r"D:\Foldername\links.txt","r")

Let me know if this workaround worked for you.